# Resolving deferred does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following method that queries documentdb for a document and returns the results to the caller.

```
fetch: function(query) {
    var fetchDeferred = q.defer();
    client.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        console.log("Fetch return values - " + JSON.stringify(err) + " - " + JSON.stringify(docs));
        if (err) {
            fetchDeferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            fetchDeferred.resolve(docs);
        }
    });
    return fetchDeferred.promise;
}
```

When I call the fetch method, I see the following result

```
Fetch return values - undefined - []
```

So I know that documentDb returns data. Now based on my conditions, fetchDeferred.resolve should resolve the promise.

This function is called from a get route handler as follows

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {

    var userId = '100';
    var querySpec = {
        query: 'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id = \'user_\' + @id',
        parameters: [{
            name: '@id',
            value: userId
        }]
    };
    docdb.fetch(querySpec).then(function(result){
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, {data: result})
    }, function(error){
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, {data: error});
    }); 
};
```

Now when I call the route, I should be getting the result as follows

```
{data:[]}
```

But the success function is not getting called :( Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: So just to be sure: when you call the function from the get route handler, you see the console log, but the success function is not getting called? Is the error function being called?

Comment: What is `toArray` method? How many times, it is being called?

Comment: queryDocuments looks like the async function. you might want to put the toArray call after you check err...

Comment: @fikkatra, yes I see the console log but neither the success nor the error function get called.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal it gets called only one time.

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331, i'll try that as well and update this post

Comment: Is `toArray` a jQuery function?

Comment: which db lib are you using? What kind of object is 'client'?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the `$timeout` service and try writing like this:

```
client.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log("Fetch return values - " + JSON.stringify(err) + " - " + JSON.stringify(docs));

    $timeout(function() {
        if (err) {
            fetchDeferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            fetchDeferred.resolve(docs);
        }
    });
});
```